# Arranging 2 strings aesthetically?

Tags: python

Let's say I have 2 strings, first name and last name. How do I add them to form "first_name-last_name" and then store it's value to another variable???

I need aesthetic way please.

I don't want to use like "first_name" + "-" + "last_name" etc.

Comment: Have you looked up how to combine (concatenate) strings together?

Comment: yes i tried "first_name" + "-" + "last_name" but that's ugly

Comment: `'-'.join((first_name, last_name))`

Comment: @theprogrammer What way do you want it to show up that's aesthetically pleasing? That's pretty subjective.

Comment: i added detail to my question...

Comment: Wonderful detail, got to say :P What else you don't like?

Comment: @trincot LOL :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
name = '{0}-{1}'.format('Satya', 'Pawan')
```

How about this?

Comment: yeaaa i like this.... thnks bro

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 3.6 [you could do](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```
full_name = f'{first_name}-{last_name}'
```